# Obtain a result of a SQL query with SUM

Tags: android, sql, sum

I don't understand how can i do for return a result of a query with sum(name_column)
I have tried lot of things but i don't see.

Can you tell me please why i have these error :

```
05-04 16:06:31.663: D/AndroidRuntime(2589): Shutting down VM
05-04 16:06:31.663: W/dalvikvm(2589): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{exercice.thenewboston/exercice.thenewboston.SQLView}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:400)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at exercice.thenewboston.HotOrNot.getSolde(HotOrNot.java:126)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at exercice.thenewboston.SQLView.onCreate(SQLView.java:25)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-04 16:06:31.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     ... 11 more
```

my code :

part of HotOrNot.java

```
public String getData()   // This method works !
{
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_DATE, KEY_MONTANT, KEY_DESCRIPTION};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);
    int iMontant = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MONTANT);
    int iDescription = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESCRIPTION);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
    {
        result = result + c.getString(iDate) + " " + c.getString(iMontant) + " " + c.getString(iDescription) + "\n";
    }

    // Cursor solde = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE);

    return result;

}

public String getSolde(){

    String query = "SUM(id_operation) ";
    String[] otherColumns = new String[]{ query};
    Cursor cursorBidon = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, otherColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String otherResult = "";

    int iOperation = cursorBidon.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);

    /*for (cursorBidon.moveToFirst(); !cursorBidon.isAfterLast(); cursorBidon.moveToNext())
    {*/
        otherResult = otherResult + cursorBidon.getString(iOperation) + "\n";
    /*}*/

    return otherResult;
    /*String query = "select SUM(id_operation) from Operations";
    String mysolde = "";
    Cursor cursorBidon = ourDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);  
    int iOperation = cursorBidon.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);

    mysolde = cursorBidon.getString(iOperation);
    return mysolde;*/


    }
```

Thanks

The error of the solution of Barack

```
05-04 18:52:01.378: D/gralloc_goldfish(561): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-04 18:52:01.378: I/dalvikvm(561): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-04 18:53:22.768: E/CursorWindow(561): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.
05-04 18:53:22.798: D/AndroidRuntime(561): Shutting down VM
05-04 18:53:22.798: I/dalvikvm(561): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-04 18:53:22.818: I/dalvikvm(561): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-04 18:53:22.818: W/dalvikvm(561): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{exercice.thenewboston/exercice.thenewboston.SQLView}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:442)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at exercice.thenewboston.HotOrNot.getSolde(HotOrNot.java:126)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at exercice.thenewboston.SQLView.onCreate(SQLView.java:25)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-04 18:53:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  ... 11 more
```

**

### EDIT 2 :

**
In fact it was what i have good understand before you give the example. I have add the line after "return iOperation;" and change in my other java in type int.
Result of Option 1 of Barack

```
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{exercice.thenewboston/exercice.thenewboston.SQLView}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x334
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x334
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3473)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at exercice.thenewboston.SQLView.onCreate(SQLView.java:27)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-05 08:02:57.515: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  ... 11 more
```

Option 2
Same error but an other ressource.

```
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{exercice.thenewboston/exercice.thenewboston.SQLView}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3473)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at exercice.thenewboston.SQLView.onCreate(SQLView.java:27)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-05 08:12:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  ... 11 more
```

SQLView.java (full)
    public class SQLView extends Activity{

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);
        TextView tv  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSQLinfo);
        TextView voirSolde = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSQLsolde);
        HotOrNot info = new HotOrNot(this);
        info.open();
        String data = info.getData();
        info.close();
        tv.setText(data);

        HotOrNot infoSolde = new HotOrNot(this);
        infoSolde.open();
        int iOperation = infoSolde.getSolde();
        info.close();
        voirSolde.setText(iOperation);
    }
}
```

Full part of method getSolde after your code (example with code 2, i have remove sting otherSolde because i have all changed in int.)

```
public int getSolde(){

        String query = "SUM(id_operation) AS "+ KEY_ID;
        String[] otherColumns = new String[]{ query};
        Cursor cursorBidon = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, otherColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursorBidon.moveToFirst();
        int iOperation = cursorBidon.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
        return iOperation;
```

Comment: Can you print the query you send to the SQL db?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. I have ever checked if i have good written "id_operation". This one ?
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
  {
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Operations (id_operation INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date TEXT NOT NULL, montant TEXT NOT NULL, description TEXT NOT NULL);");
  }

Comment: I have add the logs on my first post. Error of String ressource. It's int no string, this error is strange..

Comment: Did you copy my code exactly?   If you did, that's probably the issue, as I left out stuff that wasn't related to the issue you were having.  Specifically, the declaration of `String otherResult = ""`.  Add that back in and the resource found error will go away.

Comment: SQLView is the place where i call the method. I have give you all the code at the end of the text. I have give you too in HotorNot.java all the method getSolde that i've wrotten after your solution. Thanks to your help Barak

Comment: Hey ! That works !
I have let in the file SQLView and the method to the type string and no int. Then i have reput my var String otherResult and with your code option 2 and it works ^^  I have tried the first option but it doesn't work ;)

Thanks a lot Barak, you permit me to progress on android with the function of sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
int iOperation = cursorBidon.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
```

You are accessing the cursor without moving to the first record.

```
cursorBidon.moveToFirst();
```

Do that before you do anything with the cursor and your problem should go away.

**EDIT**

Your other issue is you are referencing the column using `KEY_ID`, which you are not returning in your cursor.

Two possible solutions:

1) Reference the column by number (or in this case 0) when you try to pull the data from it.

2) Return the column using the SQL function AS.  Basically append "... AS " + KEY_ID; to your query

**EDIT 2**

Examples demonstrating the two oprions I mentioed above:

*OPTION 1*

```
String query = "SUM(id_operation) ";
String[] otherColumns = new String[]{ query};
String otherResult = "";
Cursor cursorBidon = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, otherColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
cursorBidon.moveToFirst();
int iOperation = cursorBidon.getInt(0);
```

*OPTION 2*

```
String query = "SUM(id_operation) AS " + KEY_ID;
String[] otherColumns = new String[]{ query};
String otherResult = "";
Cursor cursorBidon = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, otherColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
cursorBidon.moveToFirst();
int iOperation = cursorBidon.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
```

Personally, I would go with option 1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Barak. About your answer that doesn't work. I have published. The errors on my first reply.

Comment: Then you have additional errors and should re-post a new logcat after making the change to to move the cursor to the first record, because what I posted was the cause of your cursor error.

Comment: I see you call for that cursor multiple times... you need to use `moveToFirst()` on each one before you try to do anything else with it.  If you don't, you get the -1 cursor index error.

Comment: Sorry i don't see. I have written moveToFirst() before each lines i use the cursor and i have always the error about the cursor. Moreover when i make a copy paste of the method getData that doesn't works (in comment)

Comment: Updated my answer, give it a try.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean about the 2nd solution, i've tried to follow the idea with what i have understood in the first solution but i've got errors on the code. For the moment, i'm continuing to check on other topics in the aim to find a solution :X

Comment: I have add the logs on my first post. Error of String ressource. It's int no string, this error is strange..

Comment: What is on line 27 of SQLView?  Since you didn't post the full class I can't tell what line that should be.

Comment: SQLView is the place where i call the method. I have give you all the code at the end of the text. I have give you too in HotorNot.java all the method getSolde that i've wrotten after your solution. Thanks to your help Barak